# Trying to populate an array of arrays of NSManagedObjects

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I am fetching data from a CoreData Model and works great. I get an array of NSManagedObjects (NSMOs), each one is a document with some other attributes.

One of the attributes of the NSMOs is a date, and to populate the TableView, I use the "year" from the date as sections in the TableView.

To get the NSMOs for each year (section) I have to filter the array. But if I do the filtering in the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" the app would be very inefficient. So I though about one solution:

Right after fetching all the documents in one array, I can filter the array for each year and populate an array of arrays of NSMOs.

```
var documentArray = [Document]()  // To fetch all the documents.
var documentArrayPerSection = [[Document]]()  // To filter per section.
```

Where "Document" is a NSMO.

And for example, for the first section we have the array:

```
documentArrayPerSection[0]
```

And so on.

```
var documentArray = [Document]()
var documentArrayPerSection = [[Document]]()
let yearSections = ["2005","2006","2007","2008","2009","2010","2011","2012","2013"]

func fetchDocuments() {

    // We make the request to the context to get the documents we want.

    do {

        documentArray = try context.fetchMOs(requestedEntity!, sortBy: requestedSortBy, predicate: requestedPredicate)

        // Arrange the documentArray per year using the variable documentArrayPerSection.
        for index in 0...yearSections.count - 1 {

            documentArrayPerSection[index] = documentArray.filter({ (document) -> Bool in
                let formatter = DateFormatter()
                formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy"
                let yearSection = formatter.string(from: document.date!)
                return yearSection == self.yearSections[index]
            })

        }

    } catch {

        print("Error fetching data from context \(error)")

    }

}
```

And the app crashes always saying "index out of range". And I don't know how to fix that, because the variable has to be global, to access from "cellForRowAtIndexPath" and has to be initialize blank.

Comment: What is `yearSections`?

Comment: let yearSections = ["2005","2006","2007","2008","2009","2010","2011","2012","2013"]

Comment: Have you considered using NSFetchedResultsController?.  It is specifically designed to handle tableView sections relatively easily.

Comment: I didn't knew about NSFetchedResultsController but I have been taking a look at it and it looks very interesting. Just don't know how to achieve a proper functionality so that "sectionNameKeyPath" can organize the NSMOs into the YearSections.

Comment: @JoseRamónRubio Apple have a sample app (originally in Objective-C) that demonstrates how to set up a FRC to achieve this.  If you search for "DateSectionTitles" (on SO or google) you will find various examples, including some which have been translated to Swift.  One word of caution: the FRC will only show sections for which there are one or more objects.  In your case, if you had no objects in "2008", for example, the sections would jump from "2007" to "2009" (rather than showing an empty "2008" Section).  If that's deal-breaker, better to stick with your "manual" solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift 4+ provides a very simple and convenient way to group an array: [`Dictionary(grouping:by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2995342-init)

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let groupedDictionary = Dictionary(grouping: documentArray, by: {calendar.component(.year, from: $0.date)})
```

returns a dictionary with the years as keys (as `Int`) and an array of `Document` as value respectively.

If you want String keys change the closure to

```
{ String(calendar.component(.year, from: $0.date)) }
```

Then you can get your section array with

```
let yearSections = groupedDictionary.keys.sorted()
```

and get the corresponding arrays with

```
let yearArrays = yearSections.map{ groupedDictionary[$0]! }
```

A `Dateformatter` is not needed

Answer (score 1):

I think you can take a different way to create your sections. Here is a quick example for you. In this case I am creating a test Document struct, a Section struct and a SectionManager that can help you return the section to populate the tableView.

**Document Struct** This will be pretty much the Document object that you already have.

```
struct Document {
    let date : String
    let foo : String
    init(date: String!, foo: String!) {
        self.date = date
        self.foo = foo
    }
}
```

Then you can create a **Section Struct**:

```
struct Section {

    var title: String
    var items : [Document]

    init(title: String, documents : [Document]) {
        self.title = title
        items = documents
    }
}
```

Then your **sectionManager**:

```
class SectionsManager {
    // Singleton
    static let shared = SectionsManager()
    private init() {}
    func getSectionsFromDictionary(dictionary: [String: [Document]]) -> [Section] {
        var sectionsArray = [Section]()
        for (title, objects) in dictionary.sorted(by: {$0.0 > $1.0}) {
            let section = Section(title: title, documents: objects)
            sectionsArray.append(section)
        }
        return sectionsArray
    }
}
```

Note I am using a singleton there.

Finally, you can just use that code to create your sections in the viewController. Here I am using collectionView because I like them more but you can use tableView instead.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    lazy var collectionView : UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewLayout()
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        return collectionView
    }()

    let documents : [Document] = [Document(date: "2005", foo: "bar"), Document(date: "2005", foo: "bar"), Document(date: "2004", foo: "bar")]
    var documentsBySection : [String : [Document]] = ["2005": [], "2004" : []]
    var sections: [Section] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.addSubview(collectionView)

        for document in self.documents {
            let date = document.date
            self.documentsBySection[date]?.append(document)
        }
        sections = SectionsManager.shared.getSectionsFromDictionary(dictionary: documentsBySection)
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(sections[section].items.count)
        return sections[section].items.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }
}
```

Then you can reuse the manager across your app to populate any other collection. If you copy paste all the code you can check how it works.